# Ruby how to parse 9am of the next day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, time

I need to parse the beginning of the working hours of the next day, and also somehow skip the weekends.

`DateTime.now.next_day.parse("9am")` won't work because I cannot call `parse` on `DateTime` and I cannot call `next_day` on `Time`.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Consider using an existing solution such as [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to check for weekends:

```
unless Date.today.saturday? || Date.today.sunday?
  # do stuff
end
```

To get 9am the next day:

```
DateTime.now.next_day.change({hour: 9, minute: 0})
```

check out: http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/change (very flexible)

you could also consider using a cron job or scheduler or some type. maybe clockwork: https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know where I can read up on the change method?

Comment: +1 for the answer, I just wanted to add: `Date.now` and `DateTime.now` are not timezone aware, use `Date.current` and `Time.current` if timezones are a concern. I wrote a blog post on rails and timezones that might be helpful - http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/